# Django transactions not working when using MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, django, transactions

I am parsing a file and would like to import the rows line by line inside of a transaction into my MS SQL database so I don't have to load it all into RAM.

```
try:
    with transaction.atomic(using='mssql'):
        with open(filepath, 'r', newline='\n') as clean_file:
            for row in clean_file:
                measurement = json.loads(row)

                current_measurement = Measurementdata(
                    mea_datetime=measurement['imp_datetime'],
                    dun=measurement['dun_id'],
                    exp=measurement['exp_id'],
                    ptr=measurement['ptr_id'],
                    mea_value=measurement['imp_value']
                )

                current_measurement.save()
```

This code works fine using SQLite as the database engine ...

```
'mssql': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mssql.sqlite3'),
}
```

... and the log shows that the transaction worked ...

```
(0.000) BEGIN; args=None
(0.000) INSERT INTO "MeasurementData" ("MEA_DateTime", "DUN_ID", "EXP_ID", "PTR_ID", "MEA_Value") VALUES ('2000-01-01 07:51:24', 5, 12, 24, 44.22); args=['2000-01-01 07:51:24', 5, 12, 24, 44.22]
(0.000) INSERT INTO "MeasurementData" ("MEA_DateTime", "DUN_ID", "EXP_ID", "PTR_ID", "MEA_Value") VALUES ('2000-01-01 07:51:24', 5, 12, 24, 343.22); args=['2000-01-01 07:51:24', 5, 12, 24, 343.22]
(0.000) INSERT INTO "MeasurementData" ("MEA_DateTime", "DUN_ID", "EXP_ID", "PTR_ID", "MEA_Value") VALUES ('2000-01-01 07:51:24', 5, 12, 24, 44.22); args=['2000-01-01 07:51:24', 5, 12, 24, 44.22]
(0.000) INSERT INTO "MeasurementData" ("MEA_DateTime", "DUN_ID", "EXP_ID", "PTR_ID", "MEA_Value") VALUES ('2000-01-01 07:51:24', 5, 12, 24, 343.22); args=['2000-01-01 07:51:24', 5, 12, 24, 343.22]
(0.000) INSERT INTO "MeasurementData" ("MEA_DateTime", "DUN_ID", "EXP_ID", "PTR_ID", "MEA_Value") VALUES ('2000-01-01 07:51:24', 5, 12, 24, 44.22); args=['2000-01-01 07:51:24', 5, 12, 24, 44.22]
```

... but as soon as I switch the database engine to MS SQL ...

```
'mssql': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': '----',
    'HOST': '----',
    'USER': '----',
    'PASSWORD': '----',
}
```

... and try to import the data, the log looks like this.

```
(0.012) QUERY = 'SET NOCOUNT ON INSERT INTO [MeasurementData] ([MEA_DateTime], [DUN_ID], [EXP_ID], [PTR_ID], [MEA_Value]) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s); SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS bigint)' - PARAMS = (datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 7, 51, 25), 5, 12, 24, 188.22); args=(datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 7, 51, 25), 5, 12, 24, 188.22)
(0.012) QUERY = 'SET NOCOUNT ON INSERT INTO [MeasurementData] ([MEA_DateTime], [DUN_ID], [EXP_ID], [PTR_ID], [MEA_Value]) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s); SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS bigint)' - PARAMS = (datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 7, 51, 25), 5, 12, 24, 15.22); args=(datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 7, 51, 25), 5, 12, 24, 15.22)
(0.013) QUERY = 'SET NOCOUNT ON INSERT INTO [MeasurementData] ([MEA_DateTime], [DUN_ID], [EXP_ID], [PTR_ID], [MEA_Value]) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s); SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS bigint)' - PARAMS = (datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 7, 51, 25), 5, 12, 24, 23.22); args=(datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 7, 51, 25), 5, 12, 24, 23.22)
(0.013) QUERY = 'SET NOCOUNT ON INSERT INTO [MeasurementData] ([MEA_DateTime], [DUN_ID], [EXP_ID], [PTR_ID], [MEA_Value]) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s); SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS bigint)' - PARAMS = (datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 7, 51, 23), 5, 12, 24, 453.22); args=(datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 7, 51, 23), 5, 12, 24, 453.22)
(0.012) QUERY = 'SET NOCOUNT ON INSERT INTO [MeasurementData] ([MEA_DateTime], [DUN_ID], [EXP_ID], [PTR_ID], [MEA_Value]) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s); SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS bigint)' - PARAMS = (datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 7, 51, 23), 5, 12, 24, 44.22); args=(datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 7, 51, 23), 5, 12, 24, 44.22)
```

... and there is no indication that a transaction has been started. The import takes 5 times as long and when an exception is thrown, does not roll back. The Django version I am using is 1.11.8.

Comment: What is your database name in when you switch to `mssql`?

Comment: The database name is "Climate".

Answer (score 0):

If your MSSQL database name is "Climate" then you need to change this line:

```
with transaction.atomic(using='mssql'):
```

to this:

```
with transaction.atomic(using='Climate'):
```

Comment: I think I was a bit vague in my explaination. The name of the database (on the server) is 'Climate', but the name of the connection in the settings is 'mssql', so I need to use 'mssql' for the using parameter. The correct mapping to the database happens in the models.py.